# How are events declared in an interface exposed in a WCF client proxy?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, events

I have the following scenario:

- One interface for service contract (IInterface)
- Events declared inside the interface(i'll explain the purpouse later)
- One class that implement this interface, the service class (MyClass)
- a client that open a channel using interface contract and obtain a proxy class, that expose all instance's members, including the events.

When I create an instance of my service class like:

```
IInterface instance = (IInterface)new MyClass();
```

From there, I can do:

```
instance.Event1 += OnEvent1;
```

But when I'm creating a proxy client:

```
IInterface proxy = new ChannelFactory<IInterface>(....);
```

How is Event1 exposed in the proxy client? 
They are events on the proxy side only, correct?
They are completely disconnected from the server class, right?

So, I can do:

```
proxy.Event1 += OnEvent1;
```

But `Event1` will never be called from WCF server class instance, correct?

What happens if the WCF server class does the event check like:

```
if (Event1 != null)
  { Event1(); }
```

...nothing happens?

Answer (score 2):

C# event is a C# construct. It is bound to C# language. WCF does not expose such constructs over its endpoints.

If `IInterface` is your service contract and has a C# event. This event will not be visible/created on the `IInterface` generated at client proxy.

WCF uses Callback contracts to implement events.

Comment: Although the gist is correct, events are a .NET concept rather than being purely C#.

Comment: well, actually, my IInterface(the contract)'s events are well exposed in client side in proxy class. I can bind to them.

Comment: @user810917: Which means you have not _generated_ the contract interface on client  from _add service reference_ or _svcutil_. You must have copy pasted the interface definition or referencing the same assembly from client which defines the interface on the server.

Comment: yes, I'm not generating the proxy class. I'm creating by code the channel: 
IInterface proxy = new ChannelFactory<IInterface>(....);
and then, in my proxy class, events are available and I can bind to them. Of course, nothing will happend because code that trigger the event is not present in this proxy class. But in my scenario, the proxy class is wrapped by some other class wich can actually replicate the behaviour in server side and trigger the event. Anyway, now is clear for me. thanks anyway.